# Как отменить подавление ошибок в php

Tags: php, отладка

Доброе время суток, на работе сегодня столкнулся с такой задачей есть некая платная CMS (если ее можно так назвать ) в которой гов... тоесть "разработчики" по 10 раз в каждом файле ( а их больше 1000 ) установили  error_reporting none и им подобные конструкции ( во общем сделали все что бы скрыть следы своих косяков ) приложение платное код с обфускацией, выискивать в коде все error_reporting none не реально... Скрипт падает где то в середине из за

> mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 300 seconds

Почему скрипт так подвисает я уже догадываюсь, не могу найти место где это происходит, включить уровень логирование debug не дало ни каких результатов т.к. везде понапихан error_reporting none что по уровню иерархии является приоритетнее для интерпретатора PHP

**Вопрос:** что нужно сделать что бы игнорировать error_reporting и выводить всё по возможности для отладки? Как быть? как отменить глобально подавление ошибок? какие есть способы?

*php 5.6 FreeBSD 9 apache22*

Comment: `выискивать в коде все error_reporting none не реально` - ну отчего же? открывай `IDE` вбивай в "поиск по проекту" `error_reporting` или `ini_set` и тебе он мгновенно найдет все файлы.... далее ты можешь оценить шаблон по  которому они написаны и вырезать также через `IDE` по регулярке всё это буквально за 5-10 минут

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность вставить дополнительно свой код в код CMS (например, дописать в какой-то файл, подключаемый всегда), то можно зарегистрировать собственный обработчик ошибок. Он будет вызываться независимо от error_reporting.

Стандартно, предполагается, что в этом обработчике будет проверяться уровень ошибки и сравниваться с настройкой error_reporting, но это на усмотрение разработчика. Т.е. примерно так:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting, so let it fall
        // through to the standard PHP error handler
        return false;
    }
    echo "$errstr at $errfile on line $errline\n";
}
```

Вот этот `if` в функции можно не делать, а всегда показывать ошибки. А лучше не показывать, а просто писать в лог, вместе с бэктрейсом. Потом анализировать.

Comment: Почему-то ни слова не сказано о том, что регистрировать этот обработчик следует используя функцию [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php)

Answer (score 1):

можно с помощью ide убрать все эти error_reporting none, вернее заменить их или на что-то своё или на пустую строку в итоге они исчезнут

Answer (score -1):

Если есть доступ на запись к httpd.conf, то прописать в нем

```
php_admin_value error_reporting -1
```

Answer (score -2):

Вставьте вначале файла

```
#PHP

ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```